# Trying to render a python dictionary into django template with javascript

Tags: python, django, ajax

Im trying to render a python dictionary into my django template using ajax. I have some results from the whoisLookup which i want to render in certain table rows. Be gentle im litteraly new to django and JavaScript!

My views.py code

```
def whois_lookup(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        domain = request.session.get('domain_or_ip')
        res = whois.whois(domain)
        data = {'message': 'whois-lookup completed.',
                'domain_name': res.domain_name
                }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

what i tryed in my .js file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#whois-btn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/WanDashboard/whoisLookup/",
        beforeSend: () => {
            $(".ajax_loader").show();
            console.log('BeforeSend whoisLookup');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            # this works.
            alert(data.message);
            # this does not work
            alert(data.domain_name)
        },
        complete: () => {
            $(".ajax_loader").hide();
            console.log('Completed whois ajax request.');
        }
    });
});
```

});

the .html page

```
<div id="whois-results">
<table class="table table-dark" id="result_whois_table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Domain Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Whois Server</th>
        <th scope="col">Name Servers</th>
        <th scope="col">Contact mails</th>
        <th scope="col">Address</th>
        <th scope="col">City</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ data.domain_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you're not using django template anywhere.

Comment: im sorry i edited the post

Comment: you need to understand that HTML is rendered using django templating on the server-side before reaching the client. In your views, you are giving a JSON response that does not involve any Django templating.

Comment: What you're trying to do is to serve the HTML directly from Django (which is totally OK), but then you're trying to use it as an API. I think that what you really need is Django-REST framework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda late but i managed to do it like this.

views.py code

```
def whois_lookup(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    domain = request.session.get('domain_or_ip')
    res = whois.whois(domain)
    l_nameservers = res.name_servers
        nameservers = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in l_nameservers])
    whois_data = {
        'message': 'Completed-scan!',
        'nameservers': nameservers
    }
    return JsonResponse(whois_data, safe=False)
else:
    raise Http404
```

and the JavaScript code that helped me do the job.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#whois-btn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/WanDashboard/whoisLookup/",
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: () => {
            $(".ajax_loader").show();
            console.log('BeforeSend whoisLookup');
        },
        success: function (whois_data) {
            let splitted_array_nameservers = whois_data.nameservers.split("");
            $("#result_whois_table").show();
            let whois_table = $("#result_whois_table tbody");
            whois_table.append("<tr><td>" + whois_data.nameservers + "</td></tr>")
        },
        complete: () => {
            $(".ajax_loader").hide();
            console.log('Completed ajax.');
        }
    });
});
```

});

This is a really sketchy sollution though!!

Answer (score 0):

```
domain = request.session.get('domain_or_ip')
```

Im not sure if the code you have added here is the exact same as in your application - but the .get() needs a valid parameter. e.g.

```
domain = request.session.get('https://api.github.com/user')
```

Your whois_lookup function will return a JSON dump to the url that you have assigned to it in your urls.py file.

So your templates will not work as they are not setup as @vishal has mentioned in the comments.